# How to get date by ID

Tags: javascript

I want to create countdown timer
But i want to get date from wordpress custom fields..
And i want to show countdown timer in element with id COUNTDWON

```
<p style="visibility: hidden; font-size: 0px;" id="time"><?php the_field('end_date');?></p>
<p id="countdown""></p>
```

and i want to use this script (below)
and my question is: how i can take the date from element 
i don't want to put date manually to the script each time.. 
is it any way to do it?

```
var countDownDate = new Date("Sep 5, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

After i tried this answer:

```
// Fetch here
var dateTime = document.getElementById("time").innerHTML;

// Use it here
var countDownDate = new Date(dateTime).getTime();

// .... rest of the code
```

It works only for first field, screenshot below:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daCQb.png)

Answer (score 1):

If the date given by PHP is in the same format then you can use `document.getElementById()`

```
// Fetch here
var dateTime = document.getElementById("time").innerHTML;

// Use it here
var countDownDate = new Date(dateTime).getTime();

// .... rest of the code
```

Otherwise you might need to format `dateTime` variable accordingly.